# Why “bear_moved” needed?

Tags: python

I really don't get what the function `bear_moved`  is?

```
def bear_room():
    print "There is a bear here."
    print "The bear has a bunch of honey."
    print "The fat bear is in front of another door."
    print "How are you going to move the bear?"
    bear_moved = False

    while True:
        choice = raw_input("> ")

        if choice == "take honey":
            dead("The bear looks at you then slaps your face off.")
        elif choice == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved:
            print "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now."
            bear_moved = True
        elif choice == "taunt bear" and bear_moved:
            dead("The bear gets pissed off and chews your leg off.")
        elif choice == "open door" and bear_moved:
            gold_room()
        else:
            print "I got no idea what that means."
```

This is from Learn Python the Hard Way, exercise 35.

Comment: Note that I strongly recommend you find a different book however, not in the least because LPTHW is so outdated now (Python 2 is very much a legacy language now).

Comment: bear_moved is not a function, it is a variable indicating whether the bear has moved or not.

When you taunt the bear, the variable is set to True, which then enables you to open the door.

Comment: That looks like a very fishy program flow as well since there is no possible way to ever break that loop and you'll end up further and further down a rabbit hole. What part of a boolean do you not understand?

Comment: @Sayse: LPTHW uses recursive calls here, another reason why I strongly recommend against it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Yeah, theres recursion but then theres got to be an end to that recursion at some point lol, I second your recommendation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bear_moved` boolean flag influences which one these three `elif` tests can be picked:

```
elif choice == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved:
    # ...
elif choice == "taunt bear" and bear_moved:
    # ...
elif choice == "open door" and bear_moved:
    # ...
```

Before you enter the `while` loop, the `bear_moved` flag is `False`, so typing in `taunt bear` can't pick the second option because `and bear_moved` is false. The same applies for the `open door` option; if you typed in `open door` at the start you'd get a `I got no idea what that means` message. So the flag makes sure that only the first option can be entered by Python.

So when you type in `taunt bear` the fist time, the matching `elif` block prints out a message (`The bear has moved...`) and sets `bear_moved = True`, after which you go back to the top of the `while` loop. After this, typing in `taunt bear` *again* takes Python to the second `elif` branch, because now `and not bear_moved` is false (`not True` is `False`).

In the game, this means you can only taunt the bear *once*. That'll let you get to the door; if you taunt the bear twice, you die.

Comment: WOW！I really get what i ask for in the question.Thank you very much. And you said that :find another book to learn Python.But i'm new to code, So i want take the LPTHW as a guidance to Python. Maybe you have more good suggestions？

Comment: See http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F for some recommendations.